# AngularJS Karma Unit-Tests issue

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks, jasmine

I have an AngularJS project with thousands of Jasmine test cases. Does anyone have any insight to create a system for detecting memory leaks within these unit tests? Is there any visual indicator that tracks and displays memory usage of a particular file? Or perhaps a command that does this out of the box? Curious if anyone has dealt with this in the past?